# How to get shipping address of customer in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want get shipping address of customer by name, city, company, or postcode. How to do it? Please help me.

I tryed this code but it get shipping address of all order.

```
$addressCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
$addressCollection->getSelect()->where("address_type = 'shipping' and lastname like '%$customerName%' and company like '%$customerCompany%' and city like '%$customerCity%' and postcode like '%$customerCode%'");
```

Comment: where you want this shipping address ? I mean at which location?

Comment: shipping/billing address is associated with order or quote thats why I want to confirm where you want this ?

Comment: i want get all shipping address of customer

Comment: i think i sshould get in customer/address, but i can't get data like sales/order_address

Comment: DO you have customers id ?

Comment: No, i need search shipping address of customer by name, company, city, postcode, i haven't customer id

Answer (score 0):

If you have customer object like following:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Then just use the following code to get your desired address:

```
Primary Billing Address: $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
Primary Shipping Address: $customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
General Address Selection: $customer->getAddressItemById();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need search shipping address of customer by name, company, city, postcode, i haven't customer id

Comment: Ok I will update my answer for your scenarios as well.